# How do I get the tax or slippage of a transaction?

Tags: web3js

This transaction :
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x47782bb10f4b103960b598863437c7957fd83ec28eb9c777f2ace12599bf7bab

It shows the user deposited 25,636,769,405.862801219 of tokens, but the token has a tax of 10%.

How do I get the tax? Or slippage? I am assuming either one will suffice.

I have checked all logs, and the very first log is still the post-taxed amount of  25,636,769,405.862801219 the user sent. I cannot find the pre-taxed / pre-slippage amount.

Comment: You can read the fees in the source code https://bscscan.com/address/0xdfaabaa57dec10c049335bdaa2e949b4ce2ead30#code. Some contract will have public variables for the fees and taxes but there's no EIP standard to publish such data.

Answer (score 2):

The slippage amount is not applied in a variable, and instead you'd have to understand PancakeswapV2 / UniswapV2 protocol to understand how this works.

First of all, we have a function called "getAmountsOut" where you input two parameters:

1. The route passed as an array of addresses [CABO-WBNB in your case]
2. The amount in (how much CABO is swapped)

> ```
> function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path)
>     public
>     view
>     virtual
>     override
>     returns (uint[] memory amounts)
> {
>     return PancakeLibrary.getAmountsOut(factory, amountIn, path);
> }
> ```

If you decode the input data from the transaction hash you have provided, you will see that the user initially swapped 28,485,299,339.847556909 CABO for WBNB

getAmountsOut on the above value gives us 38372716447302252 or 0.038372716447302252

We can now see in the transaction that the user ended up swapping 25,636,769,405.862801219 CABO for 0.034733519083724236 WBNB

25,636,769,405.862801219 is the initial amount - 10%.